# problem in coping from user argv in execve sys_call

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I hooked the execve system call and I build kind of monitor  that print the name of the file  is executed from the filename parameter,so far so good the monitor is worked fine but the problem is that when someone run a file like that

```
./exefilee
```

it sends to the execve filename parameter only the file name and not the all path .
 Anyway  I tried to print the argv parameter but i filed in coping the variable from user space
this is my code:

```
            char buff[256];
            static asmlinkage long our_execl(const char __user * filename,
            const char __user * const __user * argv,
            const char __user * const __user * envp) {


            strncpy_from_user(buf, argv[0], 255);
             buf[255] = '\0';
             printk(buff);

              }
```

Comment: `.` needs to be replaced with the current directory from the process environment.

Comment: @stark well thank you but i cant copy the environments from user  either maybe you know how to do this right?

Comment: Environment is the `envp` parameter to exec

Comment: Strictly speaking `argv[0]` is invalid there; you need to `copy_from_user` `sizeof argv[0]` bytes from `argv` to a `char __user *` object in kernelspace, then `strncpy_from_user` using that pointer.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE can you send an example it not that clear

Comment: `argv` has `__user` qualifier, meaning it's not a pointer you can legitimately dereference in kernelspace; it points to user memory. `argv[0]` dereferences it (equivalent to `*(argv + 0)`). Instead you need to copy the value from userspace memory pointer to by `argv+0` to kernelspace with `copy_from_user` to read and use the value there (which is in turn another pointer to userspace memory). This is why `__user` appears twice in the type.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE the copy him self filled i tired to copy the argv pointer to kernel space pointer and then copy it to a buffer but it didn't worked